# We are unable to detect your camera while passing fake media to experitest chrome browser

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, experitest

I did not get a specific chrome option to work fine when my test is running on the server where we don't have a webcam when started chrome per the java selenium web driver script.

The goal is to mock a camera on the server and pass a fake media stream to the server machine where we don't have a webcam. The script is working fine on the local machine (because the local machine has a webcam)  but it's not working on the experitest cloud browser where we don't have a webcam.

How to mock a camera on devices without a camera so that I can run my script through CI pipeline on a server or cloud browser?

The below code is working locally but not on the cloud browsers where we don't have support for the webcam and currently facing the **we are unable to detect your camera** error when running on a cloud browser

```
    public class Sample {

    private static final String ACCESS_KEY = "XXXX";
    private RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private URL url;


    private DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

             String videoSource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample1.y4m").toURI().toString();

    System.out.println(videoSource);

    ChromeOptions config = new ChromeOptions();
    config.addArguments( //
            "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", //
            "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream", //
            "--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=" + videoSource);
        config.setHeadless(true);

        config.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);


        dc.setCapability("testName", "Quick Start Chrome Browser Demo");
        dc.setCapability("accessKey", ACCESS_KEY);
        dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, config);
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://XXXXX/wd/hub"), dc);
    }


    @Test
    public void virtualTryOn() {

            driver.get("https://mytrialpage.com");
            WebElement cookies = driver.findElement(By.id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler"));
            cookies.click();       

            new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@id='virtualTryOn']")));
            WebElement vto = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='ctaVirtual']"));
            vto.click();
       
            driver.switchTo().frame("scan-iframe");
            
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Report URL: "+ driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("reportUrl"));
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**

- cloud browser output:

**

[image]